# Haskell - help simplifying a function with advanced type features

Tags: haskell, interpreter, dynamic-typing

I'm writing an interpreter for a dynamically typed language in Haskell.

Like most dynamically typed language interpreters, my program is also needs to check types in runtime. One of the most used code in my program is this:

```
interpreterFunction :: Value -> SomeMonadicContext ReturnType
interpreterFunction p = do
    VStr s <- ensureType p TString
    ..
    some code that uses s
```

Here I'm ensuring that `p` has type `TString`, and after that I'm destructuring it with `VStr s <- ...`. This never fails because `VStr` is the only value that has type `TString`.

My data structures are basically this:

```
data Value = VStr String | VInt Int | VBool Bool
data Type  = TStr | TInt | TBool
```

So I'm seperating my values depending on their types. ie. I have only one value constructor that has `TStr` as type.

Now I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify my `ensureType` function and destructuring code. For instance, is such a thing possible:

```
interpreterFunction p = do
    s <- ensureType p
    ..
    same code that uses s
```

Here from the code after `s <-` it can be deduced that `s` has type `String`, and it is statically known that only `Value` constructor that has a `String` part is `VStr`, so `ensureType` returns `String` after dynamically checking if `p` is a `VStr`.

I actually have no idea if this makes sense, or possible. I'm just looking for ways to improve my design with the help of Haskell's advanced type system features.

Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: It might help to describe the effect of `ensureType` in the presence of non-TString data.

Comment: At the moment it seems you could use pattern matching to rewrite it as `interpreterFunction (VStr s) = some code that uses s` followed by `interpreterFunction _ = some error handling code`. Otherwise I think you should take a close look at [pattern guards](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pattern_guard) because they may have a clarifying effect on your code.

Comment: What you're asking for makes sense and it sounds like [TypeFamilies](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Indexed_types) is what you're looking for (although not necessarily the only or best solution). They allow you to define "type functions" (e.g. from `String` to `VStr` where `VStr` is a new type), which can be injective or not.

Comment: @AndrewC, simple pattern matching doesn't work for me because of some details I didn't mention in the question. basically I also want from it to `throwError $ TypeError expected found` and do some other things.

Comment: @jberryman can anyone give me some pointers on how can TypeFamilies help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can in fact do that with the help of type classes. Whether it's sensible or not is debatable (for your simple `Value` type, pattern matching is probably a better solution), but it's still interesting :)

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
module Main where

data Value = VStr String | VInt Int | VBool Bool

class FromValue a where
    fromValue :: Value -> Maybe a
instance FromValue String where
    fromValue (VStr s) = Just s
    fromValue _ = Nothing

ensureType :: (Monad m, FromValue a) => Value -> m a
ensureType = maybe (fail "type error!") return . fromValue

interpreterFunction :: Value -> IO ()
interpreterFunction val = 
    do s <- ensureType val
       putStrLn s

main =
    do interpreterFunction (VStr "asd")
       interpreterFunction (VInt 1)
```

Prints:

```
asd
*** Exception: user error (type error!)
```

You can also make use of the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension to force a specific type when it cannot be inferred:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
interpreterFunction2 :: Value -> IO ()
interpreterFunction2 val = 
    do (s :: String) <- ensureType val
       print s
```

By the way, your initial approach seems a bit "unsound" to me:

```
VStr s <- ensureType p TString
```

Although you might be sure (by introspection) that `ensureType x TString` never returns anything but a string, this is not enforced by the type system and the pattern match is non-exhaustive. That's not a big problem here, but you can easily erradicate the possibility of a runtime failure in that function by using a special "string extraction" function instead:

```
ensureString :: (Monad m) => Value -> m String
{- ... -}
s <- ensureString val
```

Comment: great, this solution is useful to me, and also pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Clean, clear easy way:

I think the tagged union type you define

```
data Value = VStr String | VInt Int | VBool Bool
```

has all the runtime type checking you need built in as plain old pattern matching, and wrapping it in some advanced type system feature is missing a clean and clear solution:

```
interpreterFunction :: Value -> SomeMonadicContext ReturnType
interpreterFunction (Vstr s) = do
    some code that uses s
interpreterFunction _ = do
    some error handling code
```

You liked:

```
interpreterFunction p = do
    s <- ensureType p
    ..
    same code that uses s
```

saying

> "Here from the code after s <- it can be deduced that s has type String, and it is statically known that only Value constructor that has a String part is VStr, so ensureType returns String after dynamically checking if p is a VStr.

My version also dynamically checks whether p is a VStr. It *is* statically known that the only Value constructor that has a String part is VStr, but that's actually quite hard to exploit.

### 2. Less clean typeclass based way

We'll need to make a String instance, so we need

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

class FromValue a where 
   ensureType :: Value -> SomeMonadicContext a
```

Example instances:

```
instance FromValue String where
   ensureType (VStr s) = return s
   ensureType  _       = fail $ unlines 
                          ["Yikes, I'd rather have thrown a Nothing than a fail,"
                          ,"but then I'd have to have detagged the Just later"
                          ,"and then I may as well have used solution 1 anyway!"]

instance FromValue Int where
   ensureType (VInt i) = return i
   ensureType  _       = fail "Oh no, do I really have to use catch?"
```

Which would give

```
interpreterFunction :: Value -> IO String
interpreterFunction p = do
    s <- ensureType p
    return $ s ++ ", yay!" -- example String-specific code.
```

This has the disadvantage that it goes for failure instead of choosing an appropriate response to the user. You can use `catch` to recover, but again, you're doing an awful lot of work just to replicate the customisable case-handling features that the pattern matching solution gives.

**2b. Maybe?**

Using a Maybe data type in `ensureType` would avoid the annoying failure/catch, but then you would have to do
`Just s <- ensureType p` or use the `maybe` function, all at least as much work as the plain pattern match.

### 3. Something clever and new but inappropriate

Alternatively, if your main aim is to use cool and newer type system features, you could use a GADT to replicate existential types, or Dynamic to do it in a more structured, dynamic-typing kind of way, but don't; neither of these has the clarity, simplicity and elegance of straightforward pattern matching.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. maybe I should have added a word or two about why pattern matching is not solving my problem here but I just wanted to keep the question short.

Comment: @sinan Ah - perhaps it would have been an idea to stick around refreshing the page for a while after asking to answer comments under your question so that you get more tailor-made answers. I don't have time to give you a type families answer just now, but it's interesting. Maybe you could add "EDIT: I'm also interested in whether there's a type families solution" at the bottom of your question in case that gets someone else's interest up. Pob hwyl.